# PHP unexpected '(', but there is no '('

Tags: php

I'm getting many of these errors in my apache logging file:

```
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini on line 3
```

But these are the first 15 lines of `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`:

```
[PHP]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; About php.ini   ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; PHP's initialization file, generally called php.ini, is responsible for
; configuring many of the aspects of PHP's behavior.

; PHP attempts to find and load this configuration from a number of locations.
; The following is a summary of its search order:
; 1. SAPI module specific location.
; 2. The PHPRC environment variable. (As of PHP 5.2.0)
; 3. A number of predefined registry keys on Windows (As of PHP 5.2.0)
; 4. Current working directory (except CLI)
; 5. The web server's directory (for SAPI modules), or directory of PHP
```

The first uncommented lines of php.ini:

```
engine = On

short_open_tag = Off

asp_tags = Off

precision = 14

y2k_compliance = On
```

I thought it would be a caching problem, but I've just disabled my PHP caching (it was APC)

I can't find any `(`s that aren't in comments in the entire file.

How else could PHP think that there is a `(` in the file when there isn't?

Comment: What's the third line without a comment?

Comment: send us lines 0 - 15 please

Comment: It might be with other file that is merged with this one

Comment: if there is any php in the file, its more than likely that there is a ( in there

Comment: Try to start your server without php.ini. If nothing happens, try to load a php.ini only with the commented lines and report

Comment: what is the 3 lines without starting with ";"?

Comment: @shin updated with uncommented lines

Comment: @ta.speot.is updated with first uncommented lines

Comment: I wonder why PHP is complaining about a SYNTAX ERROR in an INI file. This tells me someone is trying to execute the INI file - which should not happen.

Comment: Exactly Sven - your `php.ini` file should never be executed as PHP. You've got some other issue that needs to be looked at

Answer (score 4):

`;` in `php.ini` means comment line . 
Message does not count comment lines. So line 3 means 3rd line after top comments.

EDIT 1 : Be sure your are opening right `php.ini` file which PHP really use

EDIT 2 : use `phpinfo();` and at the result page see `Loaded Configuration File` value. it shows you `php.ini` file which currently using.
Note: restart your apache

Comment: Thanks. I have checked, and I am using the right php.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

I try to imitate your situation:

```
~]$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php.d/json.ini,
/etc/php.d/mbstring.ini,
/etc/php.d/phar.ini,
/etc/php.d/zip.ini
```

So I go to /etc/php.ini and uncomment one of the lines line with a "("

```
~]$ vi /etc/php.ini
[PHP]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; About php.ini   ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; PHP's initialization file, generally called php.ini, is responsible for
; configuring many of the aspects of PHP's behavior.

; PHP attempts to find and load this configuration from a number of locations.
; The following is a summary of its search order:
; 1. SAPI module specific location.
; 2. The PHPRC environment variable. (As of PHP 5.2.0)
; 3. A number of predefined registry keys on Windows (As of PHP 5.2.0)
; 4. Current working directory (except CLI)
; 5. The web server's directory (for SAPI modules), or directory of PHP
 (otherwise in Windows)
; 6. The directory from the --with-config-file-path compile time option, or the
```

Now I check if there is an error notice:

```
~]$ php --ini
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /etc/php.ini on line 16
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
```

Yes, and error, but it shows the correct line number, not ignoring the commented lines. I also got the same error message in apache/error_log when I restarted apache.

```
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /etc/php.ini on line 16
```

The php files worked, but did not send the error about ini to the log.

So, why don't you edit your /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini? Just erase several lines and see if the error message moves to a different number.

Make sure to restart apache after changing it.

Comment: Thanks. Done exactly as you have, and this time it flags both errors, one on line 3, one on line 16.

Comment: So how about after erasing line 2,3,4,5,6?