# Keep getting error: unexpected '(' in c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.46/bin/php.ini in WAMP

Tags: php, wamp

When I try to view my site in localhost I get this error:

```
unexpected '(' in c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.46/bin/php.ini on line 1964
in C:\wamp64\scripts\refresh.php on line 1034
```

Here's the lines around that code in php.ini - line 1964 is the beginning of set_error_handler()

```
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0

set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr) {
    return strpos($errstr, 'mcrypt_') === 0;
}, E_DEPRECATED);
```

I can't see anything wrong in either file.

I thought it might have been the short_open_tag issue, but I tried setting it to short_open_tag = On but it made no difference.

The other weird thing is that in the browser's url box, if I add a file after 'localhost' - it downloads rather than executing the file eg

localhost/privacy-policy.php downloads privacy-policy.php rather than displaying it

Any idea what else causes this?

Thank you.

Comment: on line 1964 of c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.46/bin/php.ini is a `(` that should not be there... is what the error says. Maybe you should share the lines 1960 to 1070 from that file... without that we can't see whats wrong either.

Comment: nope. line 1964 of php.ini is a `(`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler i was editing the comment... my mistake

Comment: `; in php.ini means comment line . Message does not count comment lines. So line 3 means 3rd line after top comments.` - [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16119791/446594)

Comment: Thanks Gert - I've updated the question. But if DarkBee is right, then those line numbers will be off, and it'll be damned near impossible to figure out which line it's referring to

Comment: Just use a tool like sublime which have multiline edit, dump the ini in there and delete all the lines starting with `;` ([sublime multiline edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556514/sublime-text-3-how-to-edit-multiple-lines))

Comment: The other weird thing is that in the browser's url box, if I add a file after 'localhost' - it downloads rather than executing the file eg

localhost/privacy-policy.php downloads privacy-policy.php rather than displaying it

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that one of the devs had added an htaccess file that was related to the online test server - it was interfering with the local test server. Thanks for taking a look though guys.